# Spring Rest operations convert response to class

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

This is my rest call:

```
RestOperations operations;
UserIdentifier resourceResponse = operations.postForObject("...", entity, UserIdentifier.class);
```

The `UserIdentifier` class:

```
public class UserIdentifier {
    private String uid;
    private String code;
    private String retailId;

    public UserIdentifier() {

    }

    public UserIdentifier(String uid, String code, String retailId) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.code = code;
        this.retailId = retailId;
    }

    public String getuid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setuid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getcode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setcode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getretailId() {
        return retailId;
    }

    public void setretailId(String retailId) {
        this.retailId = retailId;
    }
}
```

The JSON response:

```
{
  "userIdentifier": {
    "uid": "ee63a52cda7bf411dd8603ac196951aa77",
    "code": "63a5297e7bf411dd8603ac196951aa77",
    "retailId": "860658787",
    "pointOfEntry": "RETAIL"
  },
  "resultCode": true
}
```

But the problem is when i run this code, it creates the resourceResponse but all the fields are empty. Any idea what the problem is?

**Edit 1:** I am getting the proper json response back, i'm just unable to put that into a java class object.

Comment: "all the fields are empty." What? Where?

Comment: @AlanHay the `resourceResponse` object is created but when i breakpoint and look into it all the fields (uid, code, retailId) are all null. None of the values are being populated from the JSON response

Comment: So 'operations' is a Spring RestTemplate instance you wan to use to call a remote service. It is not in any way obvious from your question what exactly 'operations' is.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating the RestTemplate? Also, what are the arguments to the POST Call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing to cast the response with `class`. According to your `response json`, your casting object should be like following

```
class Response {
    UserIdentifier userIdentifier;
    boolean resultCode;
    ...
}
```

and call would be

```
Response response = operations.postForObject("...", entity, Response.class);
response.userIdentifier...   // it is your data
```

Comment: I don't want the result code, is there anyway to ignore that?

Comment: then return only `UserIdentifier` from service, its depends on service response, you can avoid it from `rest` service

Comment: @user2004685, are you sure? then `{
  "userIdentifier": {` where will map this value, please enlighten me

Comment: @Richard There is an option to ignore the values you don't want. If you are using Jackson then you can put `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: if he ignore this value using `ignoreUnkown` though he need a wrapper for response because this expected object is nested in response not main response body